# Topology generated by a set function from a topological space.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, reference-request, category-theory, terminology

Given any map $f: X\to Y$ where $X$ is equipped with a topology $\tau$ we have a topology on $Y$ defined by $\{B\subset Y: f^{-1}(B)\in \tau\}$. This can be viewed as the inverse image of $\tau$ under the inverse image map of $f$: $f^{-1}: P(Y)\to P(X)$. I wonder if this topology has any significance on its own right. Note that this kind of  construction can be done for any “weaker” structure than the lattice structure on $P(X)$. For example the following easy fact from the first chapter of Rudin’s *Real and Complex Analysis*:

> Suppose $\mathfrak{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$, and $Y$ is a topological space. Let $f$ map $X$ into $Y$. If $\Omega$ is the collection of all sets $E\subset Y$ such that $f^{-1}(E)\in\mathfrak{M}$, then $\Omega$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $Y$.

This can be used to show that for the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{N}$ generated by the topology on $Y$, any set $B\subset \mathfrak{N}$ has its inverse image measurable in $X$.

The inverse image function $f^{-1}: P(Y)\to P(X)$ is actually a lattice homomorphism (this means that arbitary intersection and union is distributive over the parenthesis(for example $\bigcup f^{-1}(A_i)=f^{-1}(\bigcup A_i)$), the completion can be moved outside the parenthesis, and $f^{-1}$ perserves subsets.)

So we have a functor from $\textbf{Set}$ to the category of (complete) lattices with the morphism mentioned in the above paragraph, defined by mapping a set $A$ to the power set lattice $P(A)$, and a set map $f: A\to B$ to the lattice homomorphism $f^*: P(B)\to P(A)$ defined by mapping a subset of $B$ to its inverse image under $f$.

Is there a name for this construction? Could anyone please provide a reference? Thank you.

Comment: Not what you're asking for, but this might be of interest: [**On a Topology Generated by a Function from a Set to Itself**](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/pg_10?0::NO:10:P10_ETD_SUBID:135550#abstract-files) by Elmer Lorne Young (1981 Ph.D. Dissertation under Norman Levine, at Ohio State University). Note this is freely available --- look at the bottom left side of the web page for "Files 8129124.pdf (2.72 MB) View|Download".

Comment: You are not searching for this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_topology), aren't you?